# Initialize transports and axis service client taking high time in multi threaded environment

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

i was getting too much time consumed by **creating _serviceclient on stub** and axis service when ever creating new instance of stub class in multi threaded environment (trying to create around 300 same stub approximately at a time taking more than 5 minutes). but same stub trying to create in sequence manner which is taking less than second (same 300 stubs).

attached calculating new instance of stub class in seconds and _serviceclient creation.

Could someone help me to understand and how to solve problem.

Stub Creation Code :

```
public SessionManagerStub(ConfigurationContext configurationContext,String targetEndpoint, boolean useSeparateListener){
    this.opNameArray = null;
    NaviStopWatch stopWatch = new NaviStopWatch("SessionManager");
    this.populateAxisService(stopWatch);
    stopWatch.reset();
    this._serviceClient = new ServiceClient(configurationContext, 
    this._service);
    stopWatch.stopAndlogTime("_serviceClient");
    stopWatch.reset();
    this._serviceClient.getOptions().setTo(new EndpointReference(targetEndpoint));
    this._serviceClient.getOptions().setUseSeparateListener(useSeparateListener);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share the code inside the question (not as a link) that you have tried so far.

Comment: added @MikePoole